# Is it possible to replace too many "contains" by a regex in this case?

Tags: java, regex, conditional-statements

I retrieve some content from an excel file, precisely some Ids, officially the delimitor between each Id is a ','  and I need to ignore the line if there are other delimitors or some things that aren't correct like spaces etc ...

Example :

Nominal case :
value = "8000,7000,7500,840000,870"

Wrong case :
value = "8000;7000;7500,840000 870"

OR

value = "8000 7000 84000      870"

I tought at first to do something like that :

```
        while (rows.hasNext()) {
                    TableRow row = rows.next();

                    //second parameter of getCellValueAsList is the delimitor
                    **definitiveMediaToDeleteList = row.getCellValueAsList("A", ",");
                    if(definitiveMediaToDeleteList.contains(";") || definitiveMediaToDeleteList.contains("") || definitiveMediaToDeleteList.contains("")){
                        REPORT.warn("Incorrect delimitors row {}", row);
                        continue
                    }**
```

But I think it's the wrong way to deal with this problem, plus I will never cover all the wrong cases that I can face with what i'm retrieving with `row.getCellValueAsList("A", ",")`

How can I use a regex or how can I deal with it ?

EDIT : Here are some more informations for what is allowed or not :

I should have ids, each separated by a "," , no spaces, no other delimitors like ";" or "/" or anything else.
And I can of course have one ID exactly

Comment: `^[\d,]+$` try it here: https://regex101.com/r/ARlvJW/1

Comment: I would prefer `^(\d+,)+\d+$` as yours would also match `,,,,,,,` or numbers with no commas  https://regex101.com/r/LBSOIv/1

Comment: @erik258 oh, you're right! But `^(?:\d+,)+\d+$` with non-capturing group!

Comment: `.contains("")` is always true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try out a regex with some input strings like this:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class so73895507 {

    static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(?:\\d+,)*\\d+$");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        checkString("8000,7000,7500,840000,870");  // nominal many
        checkString("8000");                       // nominal single
        checkString("8000;7000;7500,840000 870");  // wrong 1
        checkString("8000 7000 84000 870");        // wrong 2
        checkString("8000,");                      // wrong 3
    }

    static void checkString(String str) {
        boolean check = pattern.matcher(str).find();
        System.out.println(String.format("%-32s -> %s", str, check));
    }

}
```

Output:

```
8000,7000,7500,840000,870        -> true
8000                             -> true
8000;7000;7500,840000 870        -> false
8000 7000 84000 870              -> false
8000,                            -> false
```

The discussion of @erik258 and @Carapace has good points, maybe `^(\d+,)+\d+$` or `^(?:\d+,)+\d+$` is better suited for your use case - however, both of them would reject a single ID in a cell. But we can only guess what the your input data may look like...

**Edit:** Updated answer to reflect new info (single values should be accepted).

Comment: Actually, `^[\d,]+$` doesn't reject a singel ID in a cell, but `^(\d+,)+\d+$` do.

Comment: @JhinKazama Yes. With "both" I meant both of the other alternatives given before...

Comment: In the other way `[\d,]+$` accept this "8000," which is wrong

Comment: @JhinKazama You might want to add what more info as to what is allowed and what not, then...

Comment: Yes you are right, it's my bad I guess, I forgot to specify the need. I edited the subject as you asked

Comment: @JhinKazama No worries :) Updated my answer...

Comment: @JhinKazama Sorry, needed a correction...

Comment: I think `^(?:\\d+,)*\\d+$` is not a correct regex, it doesn't pass the regex validator, but I think that's what you meant in the previous comment

Comment: @JhinKazama The regex is valid, see e.g. [at regexr101](https://regex101.com/r/G1gX7Y/1). Which validator are you using? When copying the above regex out of the answer, the backslash escapes need to be removed: `\\d` -> `\d`. These are only needed because it's java code...

Comment: Well you are right again, sorry about that and thank you for your patience